# react-router 4 does not update url with query parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I use higher level filter component to add query parameters to URL so that the users could share links with different types of filter.

I am exporting component `withRouter()` and everything seems legit - I get history injected into component props.
However when I call this piece of code:

```
this.props.history.push({
        pathname: this.props.history.location.pathname,
        query: { tags: selectedTags }
    });
```

it does change the state of this.props.history and I can see my query present but the URL in browser does not change. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using it wrong, your code should be:

```
this.props.history.push({
        pathname: this.props.history.location.pathname,
        search: `?tags=${ selectedTags }`
    });
```

You can read more about navigation: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation

Comment: Ah, thanks. But why does this display the previous state? If I push `search: `?tags=${ selectedTags }` it on performing an action it will not show up the first time. If I add another query params say `search: `?cars=${ selectedTags }` and push that on action the url will now display only `?tags`. Seems like there is one state lag.

Comment: What value does `selectedTags` have?

Comment: I figured out the problem: two redux actions were fired at the same time one of which is Location change for `react-router` so I went and fixed that. This brings me to the next problem which is vaguely discussed on the internet: changing `search` string without triggering route change. The reason behind this is to build up a sharable link for a sort of data mining WEB APP where making lot of calls is expensive and unresponsive in terms of UX.

Comment: You can just when object with only property `search` or use native HTML5 Push State

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same situation. My solution is to use [`pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) method of browser's History API which can change the URL in browser. In terms of changing page content I use React's `setState()` method.